# Please, help me understand this "pack expansion does not contain any unexpanded parameter packs" compiler error

Tags: c++, c++builder-10.4-sydney

```
template<typename ...>
bool foo(std::tuple<std::string,float> bar...)
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<std::string,float>> barList(bar...);

    // ...
}
```

This does not seem to generate any syntax error. There is no error indicator at that line in the editor, but the compiler stops with

> [bcc32c Error] Foo.cpp(117): pack expansion does not contain any unexpanded parameter packs

I tried to read online, but all examples I find either seem incomplete, or are not clear to me.

A simple answer to why this does not compile would be appreciated.

Comment: To paraphrase a bit: *"This does not generate any syntax error, but the compiler [reports a syntax error]"* -- HUH? That error **is** a syntax error.

Comment: @JaMiT Embarcadero does not highlight that line.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Why the `typename...` parameter is unnamed?

Comment: I agree with your compiler. You used a pack expansion without something to expand. What more is there to say? Maybe you could explain what you intended that line to mean? *(Also, please indicate where your compiler says the syntax error is. Thankfully you trimmed the code down to a near-minimal example, but as a side-effect, the compiler's report of "line 117" is no longer meaningful.)*

Comment: @YanickRochon So what? Embarcadero is not your compiler is it? Only a C++ compiler is an authority on what constitutes a C++ syntax error. Syntax highlighters are written to be quick, at the cost of some accuracy.

Comment: The compiler has the final say on what's valid and what's not. The IDEs are usually just pretenders.

Comment: @JaMiT: And also to do something reasonable on half-written code

Comment: @BenVoigt True, when it comes to programmers, "reasonable" is [quite the challenge](https://xkcd.com/1172/). :)

Comment: @JaMiT most C++ code I come across with provide barely any explanation for those unfamiliar with certain concepts, others do not provide which include is actually needed to use certain functionality, and others plainly don't work without specific compiler flags. Being "reasonnable" is quite subjective concerning C/C++. I always avoided these languages for that rason.

Comment: @YanickRochon I guess you've been fortunate when dealing with other languages? Personally, I've (unfortunately) found a lack of documentation tends to be universal across programming languages. *shrug*. I agree that "reasonable" is quite subjective -- just follow the link I provided -- but I don't see that as restricted to any particular language. Anyway, enough side chatter from me. If you reply, you can get in the last word.

Comment: @JaMiT perhaps I've been fortunate, but I find that most languages do not have what C++ has, many different compilers. Languages have different features, but they are usually consistent across versions. As ths situation, here, we're using Borland C++ Builder 10.4 (2021), and I find that it is only supporting C++17 at most, not mentioning the inconsistencies with their own API (i.e. UnicodeString vs std::wstring), etc. Anyhow, the point is that I need to use Windows' API using an IDE that has conflicting API with Microsoft's. I do not recall much other language with that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. Your function is equivalent with:

```
bool foo(int bar...)
{
    std::vector<int> barList(bar...);

    // ...
}
```

Notice there is no variadic templates at all, and there is nothing to unpack - instead, you have created a C-style variadic function.

One easiest way to change your function would be:

```
template<typename... Args>
bool foo(Args... bar)
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<std::string,float>> barList({bar...});

    // ...
}
```

This is not ideal, as it makes your template function quite greedy - it will gladly consume any arguments, not just tuples of strings and floats.

We can spice it up by using C++20 `concepts`:

```
template<class T>
concept Tuple = std::is_same_v<T, std::tuple<std::string, float>>;

template<Tuple... T>
bool foo(T... bar)
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, float>> barList({bar...});

    // ...
    return true;
}
```

This allows usage like that:

```
foo(std::tuple<std::string, float>{"ddd", 20}, std::tuple<std::string, float>{"ddd", 20});
```

But not like that:

```
foo(10, 20, nullptr);
```

Comment: Thanks. The first solution, using `template<typename... Args>` works, but not the one with `concept`. This is still an internal API, so it's not too much of a big deal anyway ATM.

Comment: answer of @SergeyA works perfectly fine with concepts. I assume that, at your time, you wasn't able of use a C++20 compiler, but here you have the proof that works as expected https://godbolt.org/z/T5dx4qvz7